# Plot Student’s t distribution with degrees of freedom

Tags: r

I want to plot Student’s t distribution with degrees of freedom 1, 2, 5 and 10; all in one plot and use different colors for each distribution in the plot. Also, create a legend in the top left corner of the canvas and also, increase the line width of the curve for df = 1.

I can do this like this but I'm not sure if there is a better and quicker way to do this:

```
x <- seq(-3, 3, length=1000)
hx <- dnorm(x)

degf <- c(1, 2, 5, 10)
colors <- c("red", "blue", "darkgreen", "gold", "black")
labels <- c("df=1", "df=2", "df=5", "df=10", "normal")

plot(x, hx, type="l", lty=1, xlab="x value",
     ylab="Density", main="Comparison of t Distributions")

for (i in 1:4){

  if (i == 1) {
    lines(x, dt(x,degf[i]), lwd=3, col=colors[i])
  } 
  else
  {
    lines(x, dt(x,degf[i]), lwd=1, col=colors[i])
  }
}

legend("topleft", inset=.05, title="Distributions",
       labels, lwd=1, lty=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), col=colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Your question would be better suited to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, it's readable and obvious to the reader.

If you wanted to use some vectorization, you could substitute that `for` loop by a single `mapply`, see here:

```
x = seq(-3, 3, length=1000)
hx = dnorm(x)

degf = c(1, 2, 5, 10)
colors = c("red", "blue", "darkgreen", "gold", "black")
labels = c("df=1", "df=2", "df=5", "df=10", "normal")
plot(x, hx, type="l", lty=1, xlab="x value",
     ylab="Density", main="Comparison of t Distributions")

#The relevant modification
mapply(function(DoF, W, C) lines(x, dt(x, DoF), lwd=W, col=C), DoF = degf, W = c(3,1,1,1), C = colors[-5])

legend("topleft", inset=.05, title="Distributions",
       labels, lwd=1, lty=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), col=colors)
```

See it's not so readable anymore, and while it *might* be more efficient, it's not a good piece of good from a maintainability or communication standpoint. You always have to keep that balance in mind.

You code isn't depending on performance, so I don't think my *improvement* really improves anything at all.